# Finding the parts of speech of a word in a given sentence

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

While reading newspaper, I encountered a sentence as follows:
"They say cost of production of cement would go up by Tk 10 per bag following the increase in taxes on limestone, its prime raw material."
Now my question is, what is the parts of speech the word 'following' is? Is it Preposition or Conjunction or something else? Can you please explain that?

Comment: It's a preposition formed by conversion formed through the conversion of the gerund-participle verb "following. We know it's not a verb because it cannot have a subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gerund structure being used as a preposition.

It's much like any other preposition of time ('after', for example).

McMillan dictionary confirms the word can be used as a preposition (among other things):

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/following_1

Comment: Can't it be a Conjunction as it seems to conncet two sententeces or semi-sentences?

Comment: If you like. Preposiitions (again, think of "after") are often used to connect two clauses together.

Comment: In some grammar terminology, a preposition is *defined* as a type of conjunction.

https://unacademy.com/content/difference-between/a-conjunction-and-a-preposition/

Comment: I must admit that the link I've given you above is not very consistent in its use of terminology. But it does seem clear that in this case "following" is a preposition (in the form of a gerund) being used as a conjunction.

Comment: It is a preposition formed by conversion from the gerund-participle verb form "following". It can't also be a conjunction; that would be theoretical impossibility since no word can belong to two different parts of speech simultaneously.  Its part of speech is **preposition** and its function is **head** of the preposition phrase "following the increase in taxes on limestone".

Comment: Suit yourself entirely Bill.

Comment: It's not a matter of "suiting myself", but of stating how modern syntax classifies words and phrases. It's important to distinguish word class (POS) and function. 'Preposition' is a word class (POS) and 'head' is a function, and that is what must be made clear to learners. As I said, preposition and conjunction are both word classes (POS) so no word can belong to both simultaneously.

Comment: Nevertheless, I invite you to suit yourself. Prepositions can be, and indeed very commonly are, used for the function of  conjoining two clauses into a single sentence. They are therefore functionally -- to employ a word we use commonly in normal English -- conjunctions.  I see grammaticians all over the internet referring to prepositions as conjunctions, so clearly not all grammaticians agree with your inflexibility in language. Neither do I as it happens.

Comment: Again, conjunction is **not** a function but a word class (POS), so it is absolutely obvious that a word cannot be be a preposition and a conjunction at the same time. Prepositions do not possess the same properties as conjunctions (to claim otherwise makes no sense at all) which is why they belong to different word classes. Any grammarian (not *grammatician!) who says otherwise is flat wrong.  There's no inflexibility, just simple elementary syntax. Here's a link to a very elementary website that may hep you to understand: [link](https://allthedifferences.com/conjunctions-vs-prepositions/)